# JsFiddle: Unknown provider: $intervalProvider <- $interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I made this fiddle to reproduce a bug in BoostrapUI Carousel. So I had the BoostrapUI link as external link, unfortunatly it doesn't work:

-Link to the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/F52y5/75/

-How it is declare:

```
angular.module('App', ['ui.bootstrap']).controller('Ctrl',['$scope', function ($scope) { [blabla... Stuff] }]);
```

-The error:

```
Unknown provider: $intervalProvider <- $interval
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues going on here, most of which are being caused my JSFiddle being unable to grab your scripts. I made you a new fiddle with external resources from [cdnjs.com](http://cdnjs.com/) and made some changes in your markup. Some issues seemed to surface once I resolved the external resources so check this out here and see if it's what you are aiming for.

### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ssjfhqh8/)

```
<div ng-app="App">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <carousel>
            <slide ng-repeat="slide in images">
                <img ng-src="{{slide}}" />
             </slide>
        </carousel>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I expected. Thank you.